# How to avoid file variables being race condition in OpenMP (Discrete Element Method Simulation)

Tags: c++, openmp, xcode10

I'm conducting a discrete element method simulation and I'm now undergoing the parallel program. So far I've successfully run the code in 4 and more core, but the data I got were all obviously not right. I figure out the problem happened because of the race condition.

I've used some file scope vectors( declared in a class by using public static vector) to restore particle related informations( position, velocity, force). And in my contact detect class, it also involves other class.
My question is, how to protect file scope variables and objects without race condition?

Here's the way I used and my code demo:
Add `threadprivate` after I declared static variables, like the example below

```
Myclass{
    public: 
        static <vector> ContactList;
        static <vector> LeftMirrorVec;
        static <vector> RightMirrorVec;
        ...
        #pragma omp threadprivate(ContactList,LeftMirrorVec,RightMirrorVec)
```

and this method cause the memory storage accumulate consistently, I don't know what happened. Below is a part I use these static vectors in `main.cpp`

```
#pragma omp parallel
        {
            int right;
            int left;
            int middle;
            int SlaveCount;
            double particleOverlap;
            double tempXmaxParticles;
            double tempXminParticles;

#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,3) private(right,left,middle,SlaveCount,particleOverlap,tempXmaxParticles,tempXminParticles) reduction(+:KE)
for(int MasterCount=0; MasterCount<DataCollector::ParVec.size(); MasterCount++){
            int ID = omp_get_thread_num();
            //right zone detect
            for(right=0; right<DataCollector::RightMirrorVec.size();right++){
                if(DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParPosx()<Boundary::Xmax && DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParPosx()>Boundary::Xmax-DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParRadius()-DataCollector::RightMirrorVec[right].getParRadius()){
                    SlaveCount = DataCollector::RightMirrorVec[right].getparID(); //get the right mirror particle id
                    tempXmaxParticles = DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].getParPosx(); //restore the original position
                    DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].setParPosx(DataCollector::RightMirrorVec[right].getParPosx()); // move to the mirror pos
                    particleOverlap = DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParRadius()+DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].getParRadius()-sqrt((DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].getParPosx()-DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParPosx())*(DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].getParPosx()-DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParPosx())+(DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].getParPosy()-DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParPosy())*(DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].getParPosy()-DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParPosy())); // overlap between real and right ghost particles
                    if(particleOverlap>0){
                        LSDmodel RightModel(time,input,MasterCount,SlaveCount,particleOverlap);
                    }
                    particleOverlap=0;
                    DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].setParPosx(tempXmaxParticles);
```

The `static vectors` LeftMirrorVec and RightMirrorVec will be reentrant by different threads to make the contact detection.

And further another question, I have an object declared in my contact detect class, like below

```
 LSDmodel::LSDmodel(TimeZone time,InputZone input, int MasterCount, int SlaveCount){
    double DampTemp = -log(input.getRestituition())/pi;
    DampRatio = DampTemp/sqrt(1+DampTemp*DampTemp);
    if( MasterCount!=SlaveCount){
        ContactParameter contactpara;
        int ContactType =1;
        double distx = DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].getParPosx()-DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParPosx();
        double disty = DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].getParPosy()-DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParPosy();
        double particleOverlap = DataCollector::ParVec[SlaveCount].getParRadius()+DataCollector::ParVec[MasterCount].getParRadius()-sqrt(distx*distx+disty*disty);
        if(particleOverlap > 0){
            static Material material(MasterCount,SlaveCount,ContactType);
            #pragma omp threadprivate(material,contactpara)
            contactpara.setUnitNormDir(MasterCount, SlaveCount);
            ...
```

As you can see, I declared two different constructors from different classes here. And further I use the instances from them.
my second question is, will the constructor `contactpara` and `material` be created by different thread without mutual influence?
If not, Please give me some advice how to deal with these question.
And if more details are required, please tell me, Thanks.

Comment: If you do not add parallel in the pragma, openmp will not create parallel threads. And I do not understand why you add a omp pragma in your class declaration. omp should be used in functions or members.

Comment: I've added `#pragma parallel for` in the main loop in my `main.cpp`. These are part of my objects. I've already establish the system in OOP way. Can't I use omp in the class functions or members?

Comment: You can use it just about anywhere (whether or not that's a good idea depends on where you want to put it). What isn't clear though, at least to me, is where you think your race condition happens, I don't see what part is parallel nor do I see where you use those static vectors.

Comment: Appreciate for the comment. I add my main.cpp code where my parallel program mainly focus on. In case of RightMirrorVec and LeftMirrorVec might be entry by different threads and this is where I think race condition happens. I've tried `critical` to make it stable, it did work but the computing speed became slower. So I am wondering if there exists another method to manage the static vectors.